# Can't run coursebuilder in google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

It is really weird that after clicking run button, it does nothing and also no log and show a clock sign on the first column.
[image]
[image]

It works normally before. However, after I messed up my python environment, the google coursebuilder can't run web application. That's my guessing. When I run `which python`.it only shows:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
```

These let me feel like I have no way to solve it!Are there anyone who came across this problem before? Any ideas or suggestions?

Updated: I follow suggestions to use command line to run web application on GAE. It reminds me here:
[image]

Update: The error message shows that GAE can't get the allocated port and domain. The reason why it happens is that when I use command line to run the web application, I also open GAE GUI to run a web app with the same port number.

So the way to solve it is to close the GAE GUI and free the port. Or we also could designate another kind of port number with command line.(--port=XXXX and --admin_port=YYYY). Or take a look at [the doc:](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver)

Again thanks for the help of [Mihail R](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1416057/mihail-r)!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling GAE Launcher? Did you try running the command manually in terminal via `dev_appserver.py --host 127.0.0.1 /Project/Path`? How did you mess up your Python environment? Can you revert it?

Comment: @MihailR Yes, I tried to reinstalling GAE launcher. I delete /usr/bin/python. Now when I run which python, it only shows the python version from MA. Although I tried to reinstall python with different command, it still only uses python from MAC.

Comment: The full command I am using to run a project locally is `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python /usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --host 127.0.0.1 .
` where **`.`** is the current directory of the project which means I am using the standard version that comes with Mac and that works just fine, so again, did you try launching the project via terminal? You can also symlink `/usr/bin/python` to `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python` if you'd like.

Comment: Yes, I just tried the command line-- but it gives this --`-bash: /usr/local/google_appengine/dev_appserver.py: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Mihail R `The Google App Engine Runtime could not be extracted (perhaps you are running the Launcher from the dmg?  If so, drag copy the Launcher to your local disk first.)  GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app may not work correctly.`    I already put .app to my application folder, is it not enough?

Comment: The `dev_appserver.py` file is created when you first install GAE Launcher app. It should have asked your permission to create symlinks when you first launch it. Also, you should not only put the .app into Applications but also launch it from there and not from the .dmg package. I am sorry if this is too obvious and you already did that but I don't know what else could cause this issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62606/discussion-between-mihail-r-and-haoyu-chen).

Comment: @MihailR Thank you for your patience! Yes, I did the wrong thing to start it on dmg. As you said, it asked me permission to create symlinks. It can run the command now. But it still has some compile problem. you could see my update in question and  I put screenshot when I run command in my computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OP had multiple issues with GAE setup which were resolved by simply reinstalling the GAE Launcher and making sure the app was first copied into `Applications` from the `.dmg` file, then ran from the `Applications` instead of from inside the `.dmg` file, and appropriate permissions were suppose to be given so that GAE Launcher created the symlinks it needed to work properly.

More instructions on proper GAE SDK installation can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads after clicking on the needed SDK and then the OS the SDK will be installed on.